# How to prevent function inside another function to refresh my form details?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, stripe-payments

I have a function that is supposed to submit card details to Stripe.
The `stripe.confirmCardPayment` is inside `handleSubmit` and while debugging I realized that my form details clears whenever an await function is called ( `tokenize()` or `confirmCardPayment()` )
How can I prevent that ?

edit: I created a `myTest()` and called it with `await` inside `handleSubmit` and it's not refreshing the form at all. I'm completely lost !

```
function myTest(){
   return 'hey'
}
```

The **handleSubmit** function:

```
//Submit payment to Stripe and handle error
    const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
        
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('CheckoutHandleSubmit');

        //verify instance and token is there
        if(!stripe || !elements || !token || !data){
            console.log('return !')
            return
        }

        //Get CardElement and attach to DOM
        const cardElement = elements.getElement(CardElement);
        cardElement.mount('#card-element');
        debugger

        //console.log('creating payment intent');
        //console.log('myData:', data);
        //console.log('beforeTokenizing:');

        //Tokenize card details and handle errors
            
            try{
                
                const unTest = await myTest(); // => returns 'hey', do not refresh form
                const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(
                    data.info.clientSecret, 
                    {
                        payment_method: {
                          card: cardElement,
                          //billing_details: { name: formData.lastnameInput },
                        },
                    }
                )
                //console.log('payload:', payload)

            }catch(err){
                console.log('err:', err)
            }
            
        const tokenize = await swell.payment.tokenize({
            card: {
                onError: (err) => {
                    //inform the customer there was an error
                    if(err){
                        console.log('error:', err);
                    }   
                    //setProcessing(false);
                },
                onSuccess: async() => {

                    //submit the form
                }   
            }
        })
    };
```

Comment: Okay so when your log statement 'beforeTokenizing:' ran, details were present, then when `confirmCardPayment()` was called everything vanished?  Did `payload` resolve first or after?

I know it's probably simple but could you share what is going on in `myTest()`?

Comment: @RyanM I just added details for `myTest()` and the error I get
I realized that the element that create my Stripe Card `swell.payment.createElements() ` was inside my component. I moved it outside. Now the form doesn't refhresh anymore even though Stripe still can get my card details as the element seems to get unmounted when `confirmCardPayment()` is called.